# Independent spanning vectors and dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $I_{1}$ and $I_{2}$ be linearly independent, finite sets of vectors. If span$(I_{1})\subseteq$ span$(I_{2})$, then why does the $\dim(\text {span}(I_{1}))\leq \dim(\text{span}(I_{2}))$?

Comment: Because if a set of vectors spans $I_2$, it also spans $I_1$, by the containment relation.

Comment: More generally: let $V$ is a vector space with vector subspaces $V_1$ and $V_2$. If $V_1\subset V_2$, then $\dim V_1\leq \dim V_2$.

Comment: Wouldn't the containment relation only imply that $|span(I_{1})|\leq |span(I_{2})|$ rather than the dimension?

Comment: No, just look at a basis for $\text{span}(I_1)$, and expand this to a basis of $\text{span}(I_2)$.  I outlined my thoughts in an answer.

Comment: Well, it does also imply that $|\text{span}(I_{1})|\leq |\text{span}(I_{2})|$, which is only strict if the underlying field is finite.

Comment: @астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг What do you mean by containment relation?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ be a basis for $\text{span}(I_1)$.  Since $\text{span}(I_1)\subset\text{span}(I_2)$, this can be extended to a basis $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n,v_{n+1},\ldots,v_m\}$ for $\text{span}(I_2)$.  Then $\dim\text{span}(I_1)=n\leq m=\dim\text{span}(I_2)$.

Comment: How do you conclude that? Is that the Steinitz Exchange Lemma?

Comment: How do you know you have to extend the basis to span the space instead of coming up with other vectors?

Comment: If we used completely different vectors $\{u_1,\ldots,u_m\}$ as a basis for $\text{span}(I_2)$, then we couldn't relate $n$ and $m$. And the conclusion doesn't follow from that lemma, but from the definition of dimension and the cardinality of a basis.

Comment: How do you know you can $span(I_{2})$ with the the vectors from $I_{1}$ and some other ones? And then how can you conclude that you can find a set of all these vectors which are independent?

Comment: We know $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ are linearly independent, and they are all in $\text{span}(I_2)$.  Thus, we can extend this linearly independent set to a basis of $\text{span}(I_2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\forall v \in I_1$, you can find $a_i \in \mathbb{K}$ and $v_i \in I_2$ for $i \in \{1,..,n\}, n \leq |I_2|$, such that $v = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}a_i v_i$, then this implies that the basis for $span(I_1)$ can be generated by $I_2$ and thence your thesis.

Comment: So your $span(I_{1})=span(I_{2})$?